# CFML issue with date mask

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I have this string: "{ts '2015-03-02 12:00:00'}"(variables.fl_dt) and I am trying to convert it using date format:

```
#DateFormat("#variables.fl_dt#", "yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH:nn:ss")#
```

Everything is ok except the minutes: 2015.03.02 at 12:nn:00
On Adobe's website "nn" is for minutes but it seems that is not working here. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you point to where it says `nn` is for minutes on the `dateFormat()` docs page (https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateFormat)? Are you sure you weren't looking at the docs for `dateTimeFormat()`? That's what you want to be using here

Comment: Are you sure it's a string and not a datetime object?

Comment: Based on the sample code you were definitely looking at the [DateTimeFormat](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat) docs.  As noted in the comments below, the sample code does not output the string literal " at " in between the date and time. CF10 interprets the `t` as a time marker. Not sure if there is a way to escape it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateFormat does not have time pattern. Requested result can be obtained using DateFormat and TimeFormat functions.

```
<cfset result = DateFormat(variables.fl_dt, "yyyy.MM.dd") & " at " &   
                TimeFormat(variables.fl_dt, "HH:nn:ss") />
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at Adam's comment. dateTimeFormat() will give you what you need.

```
#DateTimeFormat(variables.fl_dt, "yyyy.MM.dd 'at' HH:nn:ss")#
```

displays
2015.03.02 at 06:03:10

Comment: Under CF10 and CF11 this code does not add ' at ' between date and time.

Comment: That is because `t` is a special mask character for time marker. The asker probably got the original example from [Adobe's documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/DateTimeFormat) - which unfortunately - is wrong.

Comment: I personally would not have used 'at,' but it was in the question. I did not test on Adobe CF. Worked on Lucee 4.5.1.003. Next time I see Adobe mentioned I will either test on Adobe CF, or mention what the test was done on.